# Keep old value in textbox if criteria is not met

Tags: vb.net, math, textbox

I have a function where a particular value is not allowed to exceed another value. However if it does I would like to keep the old value in the TextBox that was there before the changes were made. How do I do that?

```
Private Sub TextBox20_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox20.TextChanged

    'PREVENTS THE USER FROM APPLYING A THICKNESS GREATER THAN THE HIGHT AND LENGTH OF THE EXTRUSION SPECIFIDE...S
    If TextBox20.Text >= ((TextBox17.Text / 2) + 1) Or TextBox20.Text >= ((TextBox18.Text / 2) + 1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("CAUTION!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The material thickness cannot exceed the" & vbCrLf & "total height or width of the extrussion " & vbCrLf & "Either reduce the material thickness or increase the total " & vbCrLf & "height and or width of the extrusion", "Important Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    End If
    'PREVENTS THE USER FROM APPLYING A THICKNESS GREATER THAN THE HIGHT AND LENGTH OF THE EXTRUSION SPECIFIDE...E

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Validating event and set e.Cancel = true to prevent the text change from occurring -

```
Private Sub TextBox20_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox20.Validating
        If {your logic} Then
            'messagebox
            e.Cancel = true
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
```